# How to check IDREFS count is bigger than 1 in xPath

Tags: xpath, dtd

Before this is marked as a duplicate, I need the *xpath* expression and not the *xquery* expression. So this didn't help me: [How to check IDREFS length in xPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980015/how-to-check-idrefs-length-in-xpath)

Also, I tried using id function as suggested here: [xpath: contains() for a group of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148569/xpath-contains-for-a-group-of-answers) 
but this only returns empty results for me.

I'm using the xml plugin for Notpad++, if that matters.

I have the next DTD definition

```
<!ELEMENT testNode EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST testNode
      listOfNodes IDREFS #REQUIRED
      bestNode IDREF #REQUIRED
>
```

when I get `/testNode/@listOfNodes` I have to check if there are more than one ref in `listOfNodes`. How can I do that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility  with xpaht-1.0 is:
Check how many separators (space) are in the attribute. This could be done by length of original string minus length of string without spaces.

```
string-length( testNode/@listOfNodes) - string-length( translate(/testNode/@listOfNodes,' ',''))
```

Therefore you test would be:

```
string-length( testNode/@listOfNodes) - string-length( translate(/testNode/@listOfNodes,' ','')) +1 > 1
```

Comment: This works, thanks. With that being said, I found out that also `/testNode[count(id(@listOfNodes))>1]` would work, but from some reasom not on `Notepad++`. It does work here for instance: http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

Answer (score 0):

To find occurrences of the attribute with only a single token, I'd use `//testNode/@listOfNodes[not(contains(.,' ')]` -- if I were condemned to work in an environment without validation, that would change to `//testNode/@listOfNodes[not(contains(normalize-space(.),' ')]`.  To find occurrences with multiple IDREF tokens, remove the `not()`.